# Send data to a SPECIFIC iPhone application through mobile network (No Internet)

Tags: iphone, networking

I am looking for a way to send data to a SPECIFIC iPhone application without going through Internet... thus using the mobile network.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No chance. There's only two things the phone is actually receiving: calls and text messages. Both cannot be used for what you like to do, since neither can be routed to any app.

You can't even really keep an open socket to allow connections through the internet, since the new multitasking is not really multitasking and allows listening for new data only for a few types of applications, voip clients for example. But you didn't want internet anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is text the phone a URL whose schema is registered to your app.